# React Router Dom Types looking at v6 but v5 is installed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I got a weird issue after I deleted my node modules folder, I ran `npm install` but now all my routes are showing the following error: `Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'` Which is weird because when I look at what my Route expects it is calling for element which i believe is from react router dom v6, but I am still on v5. Here is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.10",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.69",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.37",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.13",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "async-mutex": "^0.3.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.31.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.14.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.1",
    "recoil": "^0.5.2",
    "storage-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
```